# ncurses in C prints more than it should and prints colour codes

Tags: c, thread-safety, ncurses

When I try to print some values in an `ncurses` window with `mvwprintf`, it will sometimes print extra characters after what it was expected to print, as if it were reading old memory. This should not happen however, as the value to be printed is `strdup`-ed beforehand and should only contain a character and a `NUL` to terminate the string.

The error also happens when using colours with `start_color()` followed by `init_pair` and `attron(COLOR_PAIR(n))` calls, where the colour code is printed, when clearly it shouldn't be.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPppk.png)

I could not find anything related to this on Google so I hope that somebody can find the error in there.

This is inside a two-level `for` loop, where `print_tile` returns a single `char`.

```
// Convert the tile to a character to print
char str[2] = { print_tile(map.tiles[y][j]), 0 };
int colour = tile_colour(map.tiles[y][j]);
// Queue the character up for displaying
Vector2 pos = { x, y };
add_to_queue(display_queue, window, str, pos, colour);
```

This adds an item to the display queue:

```
void add_to_queue(Queue *queue, WINDOW *window, char *value, Vector2 coords, int colour)
{
    DisplayItem *item = malloc(sizeof(DisplayItem));
    item->window = window;
    item->value = strdup(value);
    item->coords = coords;
    item->colour = colour;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    push(queue, item);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

And this actually prints the current item in the queue:

```
void* display(void *arg)
{
    Queue *queue = arg;
    while (1) {
        // Wait to receive an item to display
        while (queue->size == 0);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        DisplayItem *item = queue_item(take(queue), DisplayItem);
        // Exit when receiving the exit message
        if (strcmp(item->value, DISP_QUIT) == 0)
            break;
        // Process the current message in the queue
        wattron(item->window, COLOR_PAIR(item->colour));
        mvwprintw(item->window, item->coords.y, item->coords.x, item->value);
        wrefresh(item->window);
        wattroff(item->window, COLOR_PAIR(item->colour));
        free(item);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of threads.  curses/ncurses maintain state in static variables, and are not as a rule thread-safe.  ncurses *can* be compiled to *reduce* the use of static variables, as noted in the manual page section on *[PORTABILITY](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-PORTABILITY)*:

> This implementation can be configured to provide rudimentary support for multi-threaded applications.   See [curs_threads(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_threads.3x.html) for details.

When it is compiled like this (using the `--with-pthread` option), a library with a different name is built, e.g., `libncursest.so` or `libncurseswt.so`, which has a different binary interface than ncurses/ncursesw.  "Most" programs can be compiled and run without source changes; there are "getter" functions for the global variables such as `LINES` which are (where possible) implemented as macros to help with porting between the different types of library.

Comment: So do I need to compile a separate `ncurses` library or something? If so, how would I do that?
Not too certain on how to use the functions in the `curs_threads` man page either; I've seen it before but was confused by it.

Comment: yes - a separate library.  And note the "rudimentary": there are still low-level static variables needed because of the way the library works, and it uses mutexes which may/may not be sufficient for your application.